# What is the difference between a virtual method with and empty body and a pure virtual method?

Tags: c++

I was looking at the source code for a game recently. The design declares an 'abstract' Scene class from which other types of Scene such as a PlayScene of a MenuScene inherit. The Scene class is declared in a header with all of its methods as virtual. However, upon examining the source code for this class, all of these methods are implemented as empty bodies. Is this just bad code or is there some reason why one would not declare these methods as pure virtual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure virtual method will make your class "abstract" and therefore you won't be able to instantiate it. An empty virtual method will allow your class to be instantiated.

> Is this just bad code or is there some reason why one would not declare these methods as pure virtual?

No idea, it sounds like bad code. Unless you want your base class to provide "null" methods when inherited from, which is not an unusual practice when those methods are intended as behavioural extensions.

In other words if your semantic is "extend this class and overload only the functionality you actually need" then it's perfectly fine. This is often used when these methods are treated as *hooks* and called in specific moments by the framework.

Comment: Why would you want to instantiate a class with no functionality?

Comment: @FlipFlop That's probably just a side effect.

Comment: @FlipFlop so you can substitute it later with one that inherits from it, but actually does things by overriding some of the functions.

Comment: @FlipFlop when you want to subscribe to something but you only want to do something on specific event. In this case, some method will be defined but emtpy.

Comment: @FlipFlop this is called **null object** pattern, it can be used to test if basic code structure is ok, without providing any real functionnality.